# Trying a subproof that $3^{k}\equiv3$ mod 4 for k an odd, positive int

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I am asked to prove that there are no rational point solutions to $a^{2}+b^{2} = 3^{k}$ where $k$ is an odd, positive integer.

I have already proved there are no rational solutions (aside 0,0,0) for $a^{2}+b^{2}=3$

The [proof for that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2132730/proving-non-existence-of-rational-points-in-a-simple-equation/2132979#2132979) worked by contradiction.  I proved $a$ and $b$ had to be even, and that $3c^{2}\equiv3*0$ mod 4 to maintain the equality, thus c had to be even too.

So in this $a^{2}+b^{2} = 3^{k}$ I think the way to solve it is say that $3c^{2}\equiv3^{k}c^{2}$ (mod 4) for $k$ an odd, positive integer.  Then the proof works just the same as the $a^{2}+b^{2}=3$ proof.

I'm struggling to write a direct proof of this equivalence.  I tried using the definition  $3=4m+n$ and expand $3^q=(4m+n)^{q}$   But I can't reduce that to an equation where I divide by 4 and am left with $n$.

So my question is,  assuming my approach to the main question is correct, how can I write a direct proof for $3c^{2}\equiv3^{k}c^{2}$ (mod 4) for $k$ an odd, positive integer.

Comment: You call $a$ and $b$ 'rational' at one point, and 'even' at another. Do you mean that $a$ and $b$ are actually integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $k$ is an odd positive integer. $(-1)^k = -1$.

$$3^k \equiv (-1)^k \equiv -1 \equiv 3 \mod 4$$

Comment: Darn this is clever, thank you.  I guess the reason $3^k\equiv(-1)^k$ mod 4 is that 3 and -1 are separated by 4,  so you only only change the number of fours that evenly divide into either quantity,  the remainder stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you've proved there are no rational solutions to
$$a^2 + b^2 = 3$$
Let $k>1$ be an odd positive integer.

If $a,b$ are rational numbers such that
$$a^2 + b^2 = 3^k$$
then letting 
\begin{align*}
x &= \frac{a}{3^{(k-1)/2}}\\[6pt]
y &= \frac{b}{3^{(k-1)/2}}\\[6pt]
\end{align*}
you get
$$x^2 + y^2 = 3$$
contradiction.

Including the known case $k=1$, it follows that:

If $k$ is an odd positive integer, there are no rational numbers $a,b$ such that $a^2 + b^2 = 3^k$.